# Add a element with a class and then trigger a click function on that element

Tags: jquery

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/xcmtD/2/

I'm creating a table dynamically, and for adding the rows, I click a button. One of the fields have a class "remove".

I want to use that field to remove the row if the user clicks on it, but it doesn't work, and I don't know why.

**html:**

```
<table id="table">
    <tr><td>Row 1</td><td class='remove'>Row 2</td></tr>
</table>

<input type="button" id="button" value="add">
```

**javascript (jQuery):**

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#table").append("<tr><td>Added</td><td class='remove'>Remove</td></tr>");
});

$(".remove").click(function(){
    alert("Removed!");
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because when you do the binding, the element doesn't exist yet.

Use delegation so that the selector is dynamically tested on click :

```
$('#table').on('click', '.remove', function(){
     alert("Removed!");
});
```

Comment: I use this alot and it is overlooked.  It binds to the table a click handler for the subselect ".remove".  Such an overlooked overload imo.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfect. I want to learn more about this. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Memochipan JQuery's [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is clear, not too long and probably a good reading.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to check the library for delegation.
Untill jquery 1.7.3 the function would be

```
$('#table').live('click', '.remove', function(){
     alert("Removed!");
});
```

After that

```
$('#table').live('click', '.remove', function(){
     alert("Removed!");
});
```

Comment: Did you mean "on" in the last example?

Comment: In any case you have to check this